# Border color not working for Select HTML element in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a Dropdown as

```
<select name="cmb" class="txtRed" id="cmb1">
  options
</select>
```

in style.css I have class txtRed as

```
.txtRed {
border-bottom : red 2px solid;
border-top : red 2px solid;
border-left : red 2px solid;
border-right : red 2px solid;
}
```

It is working fine for **Mozila Firefox** and **Google Chrome**. It have problem with IE 8 only.
What is solution for this ? is any other additional attribute or hack I can use ?

Output should be like below image

[image]

I have tried following dummy code, which is also not working for IE8, I have checked compatibility mode, it is for IE 8 only

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .txtRed {
                border-bottom : red 2px solid;
                border-top : red 2px solid;
                border-left : red 2px solid;
                border-right : red 2px solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <select name="cmb" class="txtRed" id="cmb1" style="border-bottom:red 2px solid;">
            <option> Option 1 </option>
            <option> Option 2 </option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your css for the `<select>` tag wil work perfect in IE8. Your issue should be something else.

Comment: Is there any css, which we can directly apply to select tag ? instead of adding new <div> tag .

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and show us?

Comment: See my solution, my be I pointed out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

add this to your code

Comment: This can now be fixed with just `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle to show that it works in IE 8 too. See this-

```
<select name="cmb" class="txtRed" id="cmb1">

</select>​
```

css-

```
.txtRed {
border-bottom : red 2px solid;
border-top : red 2px solid;
border-left : red 2px solid;
border-right : red 2px solid;
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KVVUx/) - see this in IE8 and it works well.

**Issue-**
I doubt your browser is rendering in compatibility mode and so is rendering as IE7 causing the issue

Comment: one line CSS is sufficient actually : `border: red 2px solid;`

Comment: Yeah true shorthand was enough. Concentrated only on the issue.

Comment: However, relying on user-side setting does not ensure all users have same visual experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<div>` to enclose the `<select>` tag. Apply `.txtRed` to `div` instead.

```
<div class="txtRed">
<select name="cmb" id="cmb1">
  // options go here
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any css, which we can directly apply to select tag ? instead of adding new <div> tag .

Comment: add DOCTYPE to the first line will force browser to render website in standard mode.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the Document Mode of the browser (IE9 set to IE7 standards)

Comment: Perhaps it would do you got to be a bit more precise with your answer.